# Tracking people's check-in and check-out at an event

Tags: javascript, react.js

I have some logic that helps me calculate the data for a summary of an event, which should be rendered as something like this:

```
People in the event right now: 10;
People by company in the event right now: Green Group (10), Hoppe Group (5);
People not checked-in: 200;
```

However, I have received a complaint that it is unnecessarily complex.

```
const initialSummary = {
    peopleInEvent: 0,
    peopleByCompany: {},
    uncheckedPeople: 0,
  };

  const incrementPeopleInEvent = summary => ({
    ...summary,
    peopleInEvent: summary.peopleInEvent + 1,
  });

  const decrementPeopleInEvent = summary => ({
    ...summary,
    peopleInEvent: Math.max(0, summary.peopleInEvent - 1),
    uncheckedPeople: summary.uncheckedPeople + 1,
  });

  const incrementCompanyCount = (summary, companyName) => {
    if (companyName === undefined) {
      return summary;
    }

    return {
      ...summary,
      peopleByCompany: {
        ...summary.peopleByCompany,
        [companyName]: (summary.peopleByCompany[companyName] || 0) + 1,
      },
    };
  };

  const decrementCompanyCount = (summary, companyName) => {
    if (companyName === undefined) {
      return summary;
    }

    const updatedCompanyCounts = {
      ...summary.peopleByCompany,
    };

    if (updatedCompanyCounts[companyName] === 1) {
      delete updatedCompanyCounts[companyName];
    } else if (updatedCompanyCounts[companyName]) {
      updatedCompanyCounts[companyName]--;
    }

    return {
      ...summary,
      peopleByCompany: updatedCompanyCounts,
    };
  };

  // Preparing summary information
  const calculateSummary = people => {
    // handling checkout in a first iteration to avoid unwanted checkin overrides
    const processedPeople = people?.reduce((summary, person) => {
      if (person.checkedOut) {
        return decrementCompanyCount(
          decrementPeopleInEvent(summary),
          person.companyName
        );
      }

      if (!person.checkOutDate && !person.checkInDate) {
        return {
          ...summary,
          uncheckedPeople: summary.uncheckedPeople + 1,
        };
      }

      return summary;
    }, initialSummary);

    const finalSummary = people?.reduce((summary, person) => {
      if (person.checkedIn) {
        return incrementCompanyCount(
          incrementPeopleInEvent(summary),
          person.companyName
        );
      }

      return summary;
    }, processedPeople);

    return finalSummary;
  };
```

It was suggested to treat the summary calculation in a single loop, as seen in the code below, but it turns out that the check-outs end up neutralizing the check-in count, making it inconsistent.

```
const calculateSummary = people => {
  if (!people || !Array.isArray(people)) {
    return initialSummary;
  }

  return people.reduce((summary, person) => {
    if (person.checkedOut) {
      // Process check-out
      const updatedSummary = decrementPeopleInEvent(summary);
      return decrementCompanyCount(updatedSummary, person.companyName);
    }

    if (person.checkedIn) {
      // Process check-in
      const updatedSummary = incrementPeopleInEvent(summary);
      return incrementCompanyCount(updatedSummary, person.companyName);
    }

    if (!person.checkOutDate && !person.checkInDate) {
      // Process unchecked person
      return {
        ...summary,
        uncheckedPeople: summary.uncheckedPeople + 1,
      };
    }

    // No action for this person
    return summary;
  }, initialSummary);
};
```

I'd appreciate if anyone can help and sorry for any spelling mistakes as I'm using Google Translate to write this.

Comment: In this code you can use [normal function declarations](https://dev.to/skinnypetethegiraffe/function-or-const-which-do-you-prefer-typescriptjavascript-apa). It's what they are and it's easier to read, reducing the perceived complexity by a lot. Don't write clever code, write readable code.

Comment: At the top you define `initialSummary` and then you have a lot of functions which use `initialSummary` as an argument. That sounds awfully much like it could be a class. Using a class would also simplify your functions and [OOP](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/object-oriented-programming-javascript/) is a better way to control the scope of your functions.

Comment: I redid the logic thanks to the advice received. And I will handle the functions as you recommended. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is complex.

And the `peopleInEvent: Math.max(0, ...)` calculation
during decrementing is a little concerning,
suggesting that caller might present the same person
as "leaving" multiple times.

Here is a simpler approach.
Define a Set of `checkedIn` people,
and another of `checkedOut` people.
Return size of container when queried.
This is robust to multiple check-{in,out} events.

One way to do company-level reporting is to iterate
over the set, examining the company property.
Or use per-company sets if you prefer.

Caller has done the Wrong Thing if someone tries
to check out despite never having checked in,
so you may want to signal an error.
Consider the alternative approach of storing everything
in a single Map, with a pair of timestamp properties
for each person.
Now their current status can be seen by comparing
the two timestamps to tell which is more recent,
and `reduce` will summarize that as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me envision new ways to improve this code.